# Hotkey (not global) in Windows Forms .NET 

Tags: .net, winforms, hotkeys

In my Windows Forms application I would like one special button to run a test everytime I press it. There are dozens of controls so implementing it in each one takes too much time.

Is there a way I can set a hotkey so, no matter what I am doing in the application, I can press the key, and it will fire off my event?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override `ProcessCmdKey` and handle your hotkeys there, either in a control or a form.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx):

> The ProcessCmdKey method first
>   determines whether the control has a
>   ContextMenu, and if so, enables the
>   ContextMenu to process the command
>   key. If the command key is not a menu
>   shortcut and the control has a parent,
>   the key is passed to the parent's
>   ProcessCmdKey method. The net effect
>   is that command keys are "bubbled" up
>   the control hierarchy. In addition to
>   the key the user pressed, the key data
>   also indicates which, if any, modifier
>   keys were pressed at the same time as
>   the key. Modifier keys include the
>   SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT keys.

For example:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    // if it is a hotkey, return true; otherwise, return false
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Control | Keys.C:
            // do something
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override a form's ProcessCmdKey() method, it runs before any control on the form will see the key stroke.  If you really need this to be at the application level (all forms) then you should have your main form implement the IMessageFilter interface.  For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        this.FormClosed += (o, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        // Catch WM_KEYDOWN message
        if (m.Msg == 0x100 && (Keys)m.WParam == Keys.F1) {
            MessageBox.Show("Help me!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this one marked accept but then i saw zach write `return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);` and i felt like an idiot (i use to do that but i iddnt this time) and updated my code. He gets it for having his answer remind me of my mistake. Although you had more answers. It was a hard choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one form. You can set the Form.KeyPreview=true and then add code to the form's key event.