# Tying Ctrl hotkeys to Windows Forms buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, button, hotkeys

It's easy to set up an <kbd>Alt</kbd> hotkey for a Windows Forms button by adding an `&` in front of the hotkey character in the text property of the button.

Now, I need to create a control with around 50 buttons (don't ask), and the desire is to have a hot key for each of them, utilizing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> hotkeys as well as <kbd>Alt</kbd> hotkeys. Also, it is desired to have the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> hotkeys mimic the <kbd>Alt</kbd> hotkey behavior, in that when you depress the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button the underscores will appear on the buttons to indicate the hotkey.

I could trap key events and try to mimic the behavior, but is there a more straightforward way to do this? Probably not an issue, but the buttons also need to be generated programatically from definitions stored in a database.

**EDIT:** Explaining this issue a little further, the problem is not only trapping the command key, but actually being able to trap the control key, and then being able to alter the display in the buttons to show the user what the control hot key is for that button.

Below is a little blurb for trapping the command key and the control key at the control level (though it looks like a couple of more tricks are necessary to get `OnKeyDown` to fire):

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control)
        {
            // Show the hotkey on the buttons with ctrl hotkeys
        }
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Control | Keys.C:
                // Execute the Ctrl + C button action
                btnControl_Click(this, null);
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

At the control level, is it possible to alter the button display to mimic the hotkey behavior to show the underscore? It doesn't look like you can put formatting into the Text property of the button.

The control level approach is also more problematic since the buttons are dynamically generated at runtime. What would be ideal is to be able to assign an <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> hotkey to a button. I suppose I could extend the button control to add control hotkey behavior. Seems like there should be a more straight forward approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, see the MSDN forum thread on the subject, *[Is it possible to set a ctrl hotkey for a winforms button and get the same behavior as an alt hotkey?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9fba4139-0b1e-4917-988e-ddd55a73fb81)*.

Displaying the underscore for control hotkeys requires customizing the button control.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a method as easy as using '&', but *[Building Keyboard Accelerators into .NET Windows Forms Applications](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/keyboard/article.php/c4639)* does a pretty good job of explaining how to do it.

Comment: Thanks msergeant.  The larger issue is actually being able to mimic the overall hotkey behavior for ctrl that you get with alt, see edit above.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Stack Overflow question *[Hotkey (not global) in Windows Forms .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790913/hotkey-not-global-winform-net)* .

Comment: Thanks Adel.  The larger issue is actually being able to mimic the overall hotkey behavior for ctrl that you get with alt, see edit above.