# KeyDown event in a Form

Tags: .net, winforms

I need to associate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> key combination to a custom form action (Undo).

I handle `Me.KeyDown` event, but don't receive it each time I press keys. Perhaps it depends of what currently active control in a form I have.

As I read from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) I need to

```
  Private Sub MyForm_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    e.Handled = True
  End Sub
```

but even this event I don't receive but when having some controls focused, but not others.

- More that than, for the TextBoxes I can't modify the text anymore;
- More that than, for the **TextBoxes** there is a (Windows?) *Undo-Redo default mechanism*, that should work too.
- What should I do to always recieve the `KeyDown` event on the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `ProcessCmdKey` to handle key presses on the form level.

See this question for more details and examples:
[Hotkey (not global) in Windows Forms .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790913/hotkey-not-global-winform-net)

Comment: for the TextBoxes there is a (Windows?) Undo-Redo default mechanism, that should work too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `KeyPreview` property of your form to `true` so that your form will receive the key events for all controls on the form.  That way, your shortcuts should work no matter what control currently has focus.  Here is a quick example you can play with to test this out.  Create a new form with several different controls on it and modify the code like so:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    KeyPreview = true;  // indicates that key events for controls on the form
                        // should be registered with the form

    KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
}

void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.A:
                MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + A was pressed!");
                break;
            case Keys.C:
                MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + C was pressed!");
                break;
            case Keys.V:
                MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + V was pressed!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what control has focus when you enter the key combinations, your form's `Form1_KeyDown` method will be called to handle it.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that your code sample is VB and I gave you an example in C#.

Comment: Sorry, originally my example was written using KeyUp and then I changed it when I realized that you talked about using KeyDown.

Answer (score 1):

If your form has a menu then you could create an Undo MenuItem and set it's Shortcut properties to the desired key combo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sounds to me like you are wanting a [global hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=global+hook) into what keys are pressed.
2. If you do it the way you started, then you will have to handle the keypress/keydown event of every control on a form (or each form).

**EDIT**

If you use the KeyPress event mixed with the e.handled = true, that might get you where you want to be. Setting handled to true should mean that the form receives all of the events instead of the individual controls.  If you then use the KeyPress event to handle the Ctrl+Z, then you should be able to run your custom command on a form regardless of what control has focus (according to the documentation).

Comment: well the problem there is that I don't think you can without handling the keypress/keydown event of each control on a form.

Comment: How about differences between `PreviewKeyDown` and `KeyDown`?

Comment: The biggest differences are when they occur (KeyDown, KeyPress then KeyUp) and that the KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys, but KeyDown/KeyUp is triggered by noncharacter keys.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Private Sub form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        KeyPreview = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: you should add some explanation to your answer.