# ProcessCmdKey analog in WPF

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm new to WPF and in WinForms to add hotkeys to the form I've usually used [ProcessCmdKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790913/hotkey-not-global-winform-net) that made easy to override(add) key related functionality (similar to the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790913/hotkey-not-global-winform-net)). Is there an easy way to assign hotkeys in WPF?  I'm using Commands with keys, but sometimes that doesn't work (I think some other controls on window respond to that gestures and do their jobs, so that my command can't respond to predefined key gesture).

Comment: When you say you're using "Commands with keys" - do you mean you're using something like [`KeyBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes, i mean that..And as i see that works with logic that i didnt understand correctly, related to visual tree and controls in it. For example this:   `<UserControl.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding
                    Gesture="CTRL+SHIFT+N"
                    Command="{Binding BtnNewChild_Command}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=view}" />
            </UserControl.InputBindings>` doesnt work, it cant pass the view element as parameter, tho there is control named "view" in that UserControl. Does wpf have some "common" hotkey assign scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`InputBindings` are scoped with the control they are assigned to, if you assign a `KeyBinding` in the `Window.InputBindings` they will be fired throughout the window unless the same gesture is locally overridden by being defined somewhere down the tree.

> For example this:
>
> ```
> <UserControl.InputBindings>
>     <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+SHIFT+N"
>                 Command="{Binding BtnNewChild_Command}"
>                 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=view}" />
> </UserControl.InputBindings>
> ```
>
> doesnt work, it cant pass the view element as parameter, tho there is control named "view" in that UserControl. Does wpf have some "common" hotkey assign scenario?

The problem here would just be scope, the child controls have access to things declared higher up on the tree but not the other way around. You could possibly refactor this to create your view as a resource in the `UserControl.Resources` then you can reference it both in the `CommandParameter` and whereever you use it in the `UserControl`.