# Minimize a borderless form by Win + M windows shortcut

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The standard <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> keyboard shortcut minimizes open windows, but it does not minimize a borderless form.

I'm thinking of capturing key events of <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> in KeyDown event but no luck, since it does not capture both but only captures the first key.

I can't programmatically minimize it using a keyboard shortcut

Any idea on how to minimize my for form by keyboard shortcut? or can I capture <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to trigger minimize function?

I'm using borderless form. To reproduce the problem, create a Form and set its BorderStyle to None and run the application. When you press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, all the windows minimize, but my borderless form stays normal.

Comment: Do you know why your form isn't minimized when WIN+M is pressed? Do you have some particular kind of form or do you have some particular event handling on minimization?

Comment: @MatteoUmili i'm using a borderless form

Comment: @Zer0 can u give a more detailed view of your fix?

Comment: thank you! will try to ask a new one @Zer0

Comment: I open the question as the suggested duplicate is not a proper answer for this question. None of the suggested solutions work when you press Win+M.

Comment: @myelxx If normal keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+M is acceptable for your case, then `ProcessCmdKey` is the way to go, otherwise if you want to make Win+M working for your borderless form (as expected to work for all forms) then `ProcessCmdKey` is not the way.

Comment: Hope it's clearer now :)

Comment: In case the OP wants to use another key combination for minimizing the form and don't want to fix the behavior when Win+M is pressed, the ProcessCmdKey would be the way to go, or if they want an app-side shortcut, then IMessageFilter. Both are addressed in the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2790913/3110834).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an option you can enable system menu (having minimize [window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)) for your borderless form, then while it doesn't show the control box, but the minimize command will work as expected.

Add the following piece of code to your `Form` and then <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> will work as expected:

```
private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
private const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;
        p.Style = WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a totally different option you can register a low level keyboard hook using [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and check if you received the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, then minimize the window and let the key goes through other windows.

Add the following piece of code to your `Form` and then <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> will work as expected:

```
private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public Keys vkCode;
    public int scanCode;
    public int flags;
    public int time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(
    int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hmod, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(
    IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
private const int KEY_PRESSED = 0x8000;
private static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState((int)key) & KEY_PRESSED);
}

private IntPtr ptrHook;
private HookProc hookProc;
private IntPtr CaptureKeys(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (code >= 0)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = 
            (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
        if (objKeyInfo.vkCode == (Keys.M) &&
            (IsKeyDown(Keys.LWin) || IsKeyDown(Keys.RWin)))
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            return (IntPtr)0;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
bool HasAltModifier(int flags)
{
    return (flags & 0x20) == 0x20;
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var module = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
    hookProc = new HookProc(CaptureKeys);
    ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), 0);
}
```

Comment: @Zer0 I tried `IMessageFilter` first but I couldn't get desired result. Maybe I had a mistake, I'll give it another try.

Comment: I will give it a try, to be honest, I was biased to use hook so by first failure in IMessageFilter I gave up.

Comment: @Zer0 I believe my attempts with IMessageFilter was right and Windows+M will not be trapped by IMessageFilter. I was able to trap a non-hotkey combination like Win+Z, when the application has focus, but the thing is Win+M is a standard windows hotkey, the other thing is the expected behavior is Win+M is also expected to work (minimize all windows) even if your application doesn't have focus. At least the message (if it's received by the application, is not a keydown/up/press message, it should be something else.)

Comment: Both my solutions for this question can satisfy the requirement: Minimizing a borderless form when  Win+M is pressed. My other answer is much convenient.

Comment: Same here, I tried many combination. I even couldn't find anything useful using Spy++  - whatever message it is, I *guess*, since the borderless window doesn't have WS_SYSMENU and WS_MINIMIZEBOX styles, the window doesn't receive this message.